# Change event on UI:InputText in Aura:Iteration throws 'afterRender threw an error in 'ui:inputText' [(a || s).replace is not a function'

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-attribute, aura-iteration

I am facing a very strange error when applying change event on `UI:InputText` that is inside `Aura:Iteration`. When I focus out of the Input it throws me below error.

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. afterRender threw an error in `ui:inputText' [(a || s).replace is not a function] Failing descriptor: {ui:inputText}`

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.optionWrapper.opportunityLineItemSchedules}" var="opportunityLineItemSchedule" indexVar="index">
                    <div class="row" style="min-height:18px !important;"> 
                        <div class="col-md-3"><ui:outputText value="{!opportunityLineItemSchedule.ScheduleDate}"/></div>
                        <div class="col-md-1" >&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="col-md-2"><ui:inputText value="{!opportunityLineItemSchedule.Quantity}" class="{!index}" labelClass="{!index}" blur="{!c.handleRampingChange}"/></div>
                        <div class="col-md-1" >&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="col-md-2"><ui:inputText value="{!opportunityLineItemSchedule.Revenue}" labelClass="{!index}" /></div>
                    </div>
</aura:iteration>

handleRampingChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        var labelclass = event.getSource.get("v.label");
        console.log('at 42 '+labelclass);
        for(var i=0; i < optionWrapper.opportunityLineItemSchedules.length; i++) 
        {
             console.log('at 42 '+labelclass);
        }
 }
```

Comment: can you share the controller method that is fired?

Comment: Sure. I`ll add that. There is not much in that though

Comment: Your problem seems to be rooting from class="{!index}" why would you set the class and labelclass on the inputtext to a indexvar variable? In my opinion these need to refer to a css element and not a random string(thoughts?)

Comment: These are attributes that was doing a trial and error method just to see which attribute is accessed in the javascript controller so that I can use the index value to build additional logic.